# How to check the types of JSON values?

Tags: java, json, parsing

I would like to ask if someone knows how to check the type of a JSON value in Java?

For example if we have the following JSON file:

```
{
    "Name": {
        "First": "Job",
        "Last": "MOUN"
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "location": "home",
            "code": 44
        }
    ],
    "age": 16
}
```

then I want to know for exemple for the `"Name"` the type is an Object and for the `"phoneNumbers"` is an Array.

Comment: What API for JSON parsing are you using?

Comment: `instanceof` keyword would be helpful here

Answer (score 0):

well it depends on what package you are using. I'm fan of [javax.json package](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxjson10jar.htm),

here is an example of how to use it:

```
//convert String to JsonObject
JsonObject object= Json.createReader(new StringReader(myString)).readObject();

//get the value of "Name"
JsonValue myvalue=object.get("Name");
//print the type
System.out.println(myvalue.getValueType()) ; // in this case it prints JsonObject;
```